# Disguising the identity of a voice over

Tags: audio

I consider making some kind of tutorial channel on YouTube about a specific subject where I do a voice over on my videos while using an Intuos to demonstrate on the monitor. However, I do not wish the whole world to know who I am and therefore I thought about if it is possible that my voice could be recognized from the voice over in any way. 
So is it actually possible to quickly and easily change the voice audio a bit so it still sounds natural and wouldn't be recognized?

Also, I know about Audacity. Do any of you know how to do it there and are there better software solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options for disguising a voice, but several of them intentionally make the sound unnatural.

- **Have someone else record the voiceover.** This is the only technique that results in a truly natural sound because it is an unmodified voice. There are some relatively inexpensive [voiceover services](https://voicebunny.com/) available if you don't already know someone. Because the person is never seen on screen in what you describe, you don't have to worry about lip sync, just rough timing.
- **A simple pitch shift.** Change the key of your voice with a pitch shift filter and correct the timing. This is easily reversible if you have serious concerns about your identity. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDkgoDGjaUk) describes how to do that in Premier.
- **Randomize the pitch shift, layer multiple pitches, or add other distortions.** [Sound designers get creative with plugins](https://www.pro-tools-expert.com/home-page/2016/1/13/help-please-how-to-disguise-an-interviewees-voice-to-protect-their-identity).